# Script to Configure Queue and DataSource etc using java in websphere 7

Tags: java, xml, websphere

I am using Websphere application server. For the server configuration I am restoring it from a existing CAR file. I have some xml file where i hold all the jms, Queue and datasource related information.How can i take the information from xml file in script to configure the websphere Queue.

Now I want to write a program/script in Java so I can directly configure the WAS after running the script or program instead of restoring it from CAR file. But I don't know how to proceed. Please suggest me some approach with example so I can do the task.

Comment: Whats the problem with this question?People are voting it to close and even voting down  it?Its my request to all of them please comment the reason for doing the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to be disciplined about doing no manual configuration and using automated wsadmin scripts for all of the WAS configuration.

There is a helper library here with some reusable constructs:

https://github.com/wsadminlib/wsadminlib

And most configuration done in the WAS admin console comes with "command assistance" which shows you the underlying wsadmin commands being invoked when a change is submitted.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0812_rhodes/0812_rhodes.html

This means instead of a save/restore kind of operation, you're scripting the entire bringup to make it more repeatable.

Comment: thanks.Is there way to write java program like jython script to perform the same thing

Comment: Yes, you can write java code that uses the com.ibm.websphere.management.* API's but it's quite a bit more complex

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rjmx_adminclient.html?lang=en

Comment: Thanks @covener for your help.